Handling List of Strings in Flutter and Sending Correct JSON to Node.js API
I'm trying to register data in an array for my API in node, but the data only arrives "wrong", in the case of ingredients.
console:
{
 title: 'One more try',
 ingredients: [ '["Ingredient A","Ingredient B", "sweet"]' ],
 instructions: 'I don't know.',
 imageUrl: [],
 difficulty: 'Medium ',
 time: '36',
 servings: 5,
 _id: new ObjectId('667f225ccc58dfb1e42a20cf'),
 createdAt: 2024-06-28T20:51:40.117Z
}

In the App (Flutter) the model ingredients are List<String>
On controller var ingredients = <String>[].obs;
In the view:
TextField(
 onChanged: (value) {
 controller.ingredients.value = value.split(',');
 },
 decoration: const InputDecoration(
 labelText: 'Ingredients (comma separated)'),
 ),)

If I remove the value split it shows the message:

A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'


I decided to leave it as a string and in flutter separate it with a comma.
for (String ingredient in recipe.ingredients!.split(', '))
In the model did I leave String? ingredients;

It seems the problem is you're using ' ' around the list itself that's why the message say that you expect a List but get a String. The field should only be ingredients: [ "Ingredient A", "Ingredient B", "sweet"],
